# How can i import a core translation into my own module?

Tags: overrides, localisation, magento-1

I found posts about how to let Mage use my own translation in core modules,

but not the other way.

What im trying is:

I overwrite core templates - in example module Mage_Sales.

The Block is like `class My_Module_Block_My_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template`

The config.xml:

`...
    <frontend>
...
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <My_Module>
                    <files>
                        <default>My_Module.csv</default>
                        <need_this_too>Mage_Sales.csv</need_this_too> 
                    </files>
                </My_Module>
            </modules>
        </translate>
...
    </frontend>`

I think i tried every combination -- from using path `app/locale/de_DE/Mage_Sales.csv` to `translate>modules>Mage_Sales>files>default>Mage_Sales.csv` but nothing works.

Is there a way to **import core translation .csv to my module** ?

Comment: why don't you use theme translate, which is more important than module translate?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In the rewritten block, add the following method:

```
public function getModuleName()
{
    return 'Mage_Sales';
}
```

This way, the module used for translations is not determined by the class name anymore and the translations of `Mage_Sales` will be used.

If you need your own translations additionally, you can always use the module explicitly:

```
Mage::helper('my_module')->__('text to translate')
```